# webdynpro abap get cookies

Tags: cookies, abap, webdynpro

I have a requirement where I need to embed an external application into webDynpro ABAP, which I am planning to embed using IFrame.

I also need to read the cookie information from this external application into WebDynpro ABAP.

Any ideas how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

There's an IFrame component you can use to embed the external app.
WDA does not provide access to cookies though (and unless both apps are on the same domain, they wouldn't be able to access eachothers cookies anyway).

Comment: both the apps are on the same domain.. is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a bit ancient technique, but it actually works:

- create BSP app on your SAP server with frameset and two frames
- one frame will have 100% height and it will contain your external app
- other frame will have zero height (so it will be invisible) and it will contain view of your BSP application and javascript code
- view will contain form with hidden fields
- javascript code will get cookies from visible frame and fill the values into the hidden fields and submit the form (this is the place, which assume you can reach content from frame to frame, otherwise you will face cross-site-scripting issue)
- BSP application on ABAP side will receive the cookie values this way as form data and can deliver it on server side somehow to webdynpro application (through shared memory or something)

Does this sound like a solution?